# Выход из аккаунта без перехода на страницу /exit

Tags: django, url, redirect

Нужно реализовать выход из аккаунта без переадресации на страницу /exit, а сделать скажем так: пользователь нажал "Выйти из аккаунта" и его перенаправило на ту страницу, которую я укажу (на главную). Вот как сейчас реализована эта функция:

urls. py:

```
path('exit/', authViews.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/exit.html'), name='exit'),
```

exit.html:

```
{% extends 'main_page/main.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block main_block %}
  <div class="form-section mr_for_users">
    <h2>Вы успешно вышли из аккаунта!</h2>
    <a href="{% url 'auth' %}">Войти снова</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Пробовал менять url путь на " ", а шаблон на шаблон главной страницу, но не получается. Если у кого есть идеи буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте в settings.py добавить строчку

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'ваш_url'
```